# django nginx gunicorn,, start: Job failed to start

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

every one I am trying to deploying django project using nginx gunicorn,,but when I run

sudo service gunicorn start,
it said, 
 start: Job failed to start,

here it the working path,,
[image]

the gunicorn.conf file

> /etc/init/gunicorn.conf

```
description "Gunicorn application server handling myproject"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
setuid user
setgid www-data
chdir /home/parallels/books/mysite


exec myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/parallels/books/mysite/mysite.sock mysite.wsgi:application
```

when I run

> gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 mysite.wsgi:application

I can see  mysite running

[image]

but when I try

> sudo service gunicorn start

fail,,,
[image]
I just [following the instruction here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-14-04)

any one who can reply thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

I know this is too late, but in any case:

1. In your gunicorn.conf I see `setuid user` but there is user `parallels` in your prompt (it depends of your bash settings, but probably it is name of curent user).
2. There is `chdir /home/parallels/books/mysite` and then `exec myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn` and I guess your gunicorn location is **not**
   `/home/parallels/books/mysite/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn`. So you need to use appropriate path to run gunicorn.

Check gunicorn log file to find out problems. It should be here `/var/log/upstart/gunicorn.log`

Answer (score 2):

You need to update `setuid user` to your user name and also the path.

Comment: @JoeLin could you please help us with what exactly from all the answers working for you? You are mentioning thanks for every answers :)

Answer (score 1):

Check the exec command and its parameters. If you have any problem in that it will fail

In my case I missed bin after venv (virtual env) path.
ie exec myprojectenv/**bin**/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind ...